# parse function in date-fns returns one day previous value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, date-fns

I am trying to parse date using date-fns library but getting one day previous as result. How can I avoid this and get the right result?

```
start = '2021-08-16'
const parseStart = parse(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date());
```

output:

```
2021-08-15T18:30:00.000Z
```

Comment: Welcome to timezones :) `new Date("2021-08-15T18:30:00.000Z")` should transform it back to your timezone

Comment: @dbuchet I knew this is related to timezones. God, I hate dates. Can you give some references to how can I modify parse with tz. Thanks, man :)

Comment: Its is giving you the UTC time, convert it to your local time and you will good to go

Comment: You have `date-fns-tz` if you need to deal with timezones. And good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to have this timezone overhead I'd suggest formatting your date string into ISO string and then using `parseISO` function of date-fns.

Like this:

```
import { parseISO } from 'date-fns';

const parseStringDate = (dateString: string): Date => {
  const ISODate = new Date(dateString).toISOString();
  return parseISO(ISODate);
};

parseStringDate("2021-08-19") //2021-08-19T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Hi, if I have a datestring formatted like this "yyyyMMdd", conversion give me an error

Comment: @P_R In your case, I'd suggest reformatting your date string first: ```const format = (date: string) => {
    const year = date.substring(0, 4);
    const month = date.substring(4, 6);
    const day = date.substring(6, 8);
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  };```

Comment: I made exactly like this

Answer (score 8):

We had a similar problem while trying to use the date-fns format function on a hyphened string date. It was subtracting one day from the date while formating. The solution was in fact to change the hypes for slashes.

```
const dateString = '2010-08-03'
const date = new Date(dateString.replace(/-/g, '/'))
```

Comment: const formatDate = (d: string) =>
    format(new Date(d.replaceAll('-', '/').split('T')[0]), 'dd-MM-yyyy') for ISOstrings seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I was using in a filter so the initial value was with "-" and i have to replace it for using "/" as well, it work's like a charm

> ```
> filters: {
>     formatedDate(value) {
>         value = value.replaceAll('-', '/')
>         return format(new Date(value), 'd MMM')
>     }
> },
> ```

and append it in html with a pipe like this

> {{ date | formatedDate }}

so the output on the screen was

[image: day month]

for a string '2022-10-21'

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me, because the timezone was still not being unconsidered. Instead, I used:

```
import { isValid } from 'date-fns' 

let removeTimezone = (date) => {
   date = new Date(date);
   return new Date(
     date.valueOf() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
   );
};
   
const date = '2023-01-22'
const dtDateOnly = removeTimezone(date)
if(!isValid(dtDateOnly)) console.log("cannot convert to date")
else console.log(dtDateOnly)
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me (v.2+):

```
// wrong:
const date = format(new Date('2021-10-01'),'dd/MM/yyyy')
console.log(date) // "30/09/2021"

// ok:
const date = format(new Date('2021/10/01'),'dd/MM/yyyy')
console.log(date) // "01/10/2021"
```